# Deploying a Worklight application to production environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I did a worklight app with worklight6.0.0, which has some http adapters that works fine with my liberty profile in eclipse.

now i want to transport this app to a websphere 8.0.0.6 environment, but when i did that i recieve this message in the catlog:

```
info: {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"ajjqfhmo88gqmm955r2p22vq7j"}}}*/

error: defaultOptions:onFailure Procedure invocation error.
```

and this is another error:

```
[Http://190.246.205.5:9081/WorklightPocProj/apps/services/../../invoke] failure. state: 500, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

defaultOptions:onFailure The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.
```

I put a call on the wlinit to a dummy adapter and the response is correctly,  this error that the app give to me happens just after i call this method:

handler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});

So I've change the worklight.properties and redeploy the .war, then, I've deploy that .war on the WAS and install the all.wlapp and all the .adapter files.
and i can see all the file deployed in my worklight console, and my android app connects to the worklight server correctly

In this .war, i have another app (a facebook app) which doesnt have any adapter and works fine.

This is my code realm:

```
<securityTests>
    <!-- 
    <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
        <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

    <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
        <testAppAuthenticity/> 
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
        <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
    </mobileSecurityTest>

    <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
        <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/>
    </webSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
    -->
    <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
        <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest> 
    <customSecurityTest name="SimpleAuthAdapterTest">
        <test realm="SimpleAuthRealm" isInternalUserID="true" />

    </customSecurityTest>       

</securityTests> 

<realms>
    <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <realm name="WorklightConsole" loginModule="requireLogin">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
    </realm>
    <realm name="SimpleAuthRealm" loginModule="SimpleAuthLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-function" value="SimpleAuthAdapter.onAuthRequired" />
        <parameter name="logout-function" value="SimpleAuthAdapter.onLogout" />
    </realm>
    <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
    </realm>
    <!-- For websphere -->
    <!-- realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
        <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
    </realm -->
</realms>

<loginModules>
<loginModule name="SimpleAuthLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
    <loginModule name="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="requireLogin">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <!-- For websphere -->
    <!-- loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule -->

    <!-- For enabling SSO with no-provisioning device authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->
    <!-- For enabling SSO with auto-provisioning device authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->
</loginModules>
```

and this is my a part of my ChallengeHandler code:

```
var handler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("SimpleAuthRealm");
var busyInd;
function login() {
busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {
    text : 'Verificando credenciales...'
});
busyInd.show();

var username = $('#AuthUsername').val();
var password = $('#AuthPassword').val();
usuario1 = username;
password1 = password;
var invocationData = {
    adapter : "SimpleAuthAdapter",
    procedure : "submitAuthentication",
    parameters : [ "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password),
            username ]
};

handler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});
};
```

Is there something that I'm missing or I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: this error happens because the application security was enabled on the was server without setting any role on the web.xml file.